# How do I access my apache server from a virtualbox vm? (both windows)

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, apache-http-server, wamp

host: Windows Pro 7 x64, wamp installed, default settings

guests: 3 x Windows XP

How do I access my wamp server from my virtual machines without making it available to the internet? (you know, that handy menu option wamp has: "Put Online" and "Put Offline")

Comment: How did you set up the network adapter in the virtual OS's settings in VirtualBox?

Comment: I can set it up in any way, I don't think there is a problem in changing it. I tried my best at googling this, but most people seem to have Ubuntu or other linux distributions as their host, so it didn't help me a lot.

Comment: You misunderstood. When you right-click a virtual machine in the **VirtualBox Manager**, which setting do you have under `Settings > Network > Adapter 1`? (i.e. `NAT`, `Bridged Adapter`, `Internal Network`, `Host-only Adapter`, or `Generic Driver`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a day of tweaking I think the solution was there since the beginning. I got it working, not sure yet how.

Here's my setup on my XP guest: two networks, one NAT (for internet access) and the other one Host-Only; In VirtualBox>Preferences>Network>(NetworkName) I disabled DHCP. The rest is default.

Now from the guest XP I can access my apache on 10.0.2.2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure WAMP to listen on a local IP address and configure your firewall to disallow incoming requests on port 80 to your machine (aka, not redirecting port 80 requests you your machine), you should be good.

Alternatively, you could configure WAMP to only listen to local host and configure your VMs to use a Host-only network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have selected NAT and leave standard DHCP settings alone.

In your guest edit your hosts files (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) and for each of your sites, just add the host ip, like:

```
10.0.2.2 localhost.ilovemymac.tld
```

Replace the site names with yours.